# Proper and common nouns

Tags: nouns

Does placing a possesive pronoun in front of a common noun create a proper noun?
For instance:

> 1. At night, the city's illumination blocks the night-time stars.

> 2. At night, our city's illumination blocks the night-time stars.

In example 2, has *our* created a proper noun?

Comment: I understand your thinking here. Proper nouns are associated with one-off/individualised referents. And yes, adding 'our' _particularises_ 'city'. But it's not awarded titular status (John / King Edward / Paris and Lyons / the Mediterranean ...).

Answer (score 1):

NO!

Proper nouns are the nouns that are specific to objects. In other words, they are ***names*** of things and people.

In your second example, it's still a noun.

Proper noun does not depend on any pronoun.

> This is New York 
>  My New York is beautiful.

Whether it's yours or someone else's, NYC remains a proper noun.

---

BTW, you need an apostrophe -
*"....our cities' illumination ...."*

Comment: That should be "Our city's illumination..."